# Php program on HTML, doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I have a .htm file that is spouse to have a navigation bar. since i need this bar on other .htm files too, I put a  php include 'nav_bar.php'; (with  element, but it won't work. The nav_bar.php is: `<?php echo ' (navigation html)';?>`. The thing is, the browser (chrome)  doesn't ever read the include command, it just puts it as a comment. 
So what did I do wrong?
All I want is a few .html pages to contain the same navigation menu, from one source (so its easier to change all the menus). How can I do that?

This is the main.html code (the file that meed to include the menu) and below is the .php file that echos the menu. What is wrong? (I'm using Microsoft Expression Web 4 if it madders)

```
--main.html--

`<!DOCTYPE html >`

`<html>`

`<head>`

`//some code....`

`</head>`

`<body dir="rtl">`

`//some class I made in the style sheets.(its not important right now)`

`<div id="page" class="contaner1">`

`<div id="textErea" class="contaner2">`

`<?php include 'navMenu.php';?>`

`//some code...`

`</div></div>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

the .php file:

--navMenu.php--

`<?php echo '/*some html code...*/';?>`
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, this is impossible. So please post the code. However, guessing, you are including php code in a .html-file, which does not work. Change the filetype to .php and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: do use php in a file, it has to run via php on the server

Comment: i don't have a server. if i change it to a php file, i need to do the entire thing a php program that echos to code? is that wat relly shoul be done?

Comment: i changed it to a .php file. how do i make it run as a html page?

Answer (score 2):

Wamp, That is Apache, is setup to only run php code in files that have an extension of .php, thats why the php code is not executing.

Its not recommended but you can make php code run in .htm files like this

create a .htaccess file in the folder containing this specific site and add thsi line to it.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your server to know what interpreter to use, it needs to see the correct file type. For PHP files, that's the `.php` extension.

There *are* ways for you to have PHP code executed in a different file though. For that you'd need to add a command similar to this to an `.htaccess` file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

(The example is for an Apache server)

Comment: i'm not using a server. it is just a HTML page. i changed it to a .php file. how do i make it run as a html page?

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of PHP interpreter to execute the PHP code. The easiest way to do that is with a WAMP or LAMP installation.

Answer (score 0):

A little correction for some previous comments:

Add this to .htaccess

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

Answer (score -1):

i didn't fully understand your question but if i get it right you can use include_once in php  to include it in every page this is it's manual :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: i want to include a php command inside a html page. i changed the page to a .php file. how do i make it run as a html page?